# subprocess.call crashes, while os.system works in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I've noticed that after I load my input(big) files, the subprocess.call("") arises an error:

```
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

However the os.system("") still works. 
(As an example I used "ls -ltr" for )

How this behavior could be explain? 
Does it has something to do with how python arranges memory? 
Or this is a sign of a potential problem?

Comment: I'm pretty sure we'll need more information. What calls are you making? I suspect not an empty string. I can surely tell that something's happening.

Comment: @AndrasDeak , just for a check I passed the "ls -ltr" command.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Please put together a [mcve], it shouldn't be too long for what you're seeing.

Comment: I don't see the way how I could do so without attaching the big input files

Comment: Well, `ls -ltr` just lists files, right? The fact that those files are big or small is irrelevant. Do you "load your input files" with `ls`? I doubt it. But if the problem already happens with `ls`, you can use that as an MCVE. Am I missing something? Are you omitting something?

Comment: I've executed `ls -ltr` before and after loading the file. In case I was using subprocess: it rised an error to run  `ls -ltr` after loading the files. In case I was using os: no problem occurred neither before nor after loading the files.